# How to differentiate active and passive buzzers in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino starter set, which came with both an active and a passive buzzer.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to know which is which.  All I know is that one is a little longer than the other one, on which I can see the green circuit board underneath.

Comment: have you considered entering active or passive buzzer on www.google.com? it will give you plenty of answers...
http://download2.nust.na/pub4/sourceforge/d/di/diyarduinoboards/Buzzers/Difference%20between%20passive%20and%20active%20buzzers.pdf

Comment: That's what happens when you buy a grab bag of electronics with no datasheets for each part.  Oh, and this is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is has nothing to do with programming; it's about selection of electronic parts.

Answer (score 4):

An active buzzer generates the sound itself. You basically just turn it on or off.
A passive buzzer needs a signal source that provides the sound signal.

To find out which is which you can measure the resistance between both leads. If it is a few Ohms its the passive one, higher values indicate an active one.
Also the active one will have it's own circuitry (the pcb you can see) and will therefor be probably bigger.

But I guess your arduino package comes with a parts list that should give you all information you need?

Comment: however, on the smaller buzzer, i can see a + and a -, whereas on the larger one, there isn't anything

Answer (score 3):

"Programatically" speaking:

- Active Buzzer: using a simple digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH) will turn the beep on, once it has a internal oscillator.
- Passive Buzzer: you need to use Tone() function in order to make it beep. Once it has no internal oscillator you need to use Tone() function to create the frequency it will oscillate. Check the [Tone() reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone) page to learn how to use it, but is quite simple, you just need to enter as parameter pin and frequency like *Tone(3, 440)*, will generate a 440Hz on passive buzzer hooked up to pin 3.

To stop a active buzzer you need to use digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW), while with a passive buzzer you need to use noTone(passiveBuzzerPin).

Answer (score 1):

How to distinguish passive buzzer and active buzzer?

There are several ways to distinguish passive buzzer and active buzzer.
The most simple method is to watch their different appearances.If you can see a drive board,it is passive buzzer.If the buzzer is completely covered by black adhesive,it is active buzzer.

https://www.keliking.com/Differences-Between-Passive-Buzzer-and-Active-Buzzer-id570060.html

Answer (score 0):

They come in all shapes and sizes, so don't assume "long" means one thing or another. The passive buzzer has only a small piezo on the module's PCB. An active buzzer will have a couple other small components on the pcb, like an amp and resistor(s).

Answer (score 0):

In the Freenove Arduino kit that i bought, the passive buzzer is the one with the green on the bottom and the active is the one without, and is slightly taller with varied hights of the pins

Answer (score 0):

Physical distinction between the two.

Slight disclaimer first. . . the buzzers I have are from one of those 27 piece sensor kits. For me it was an extra buy from "30 Days Lost In Space". After my pieces all got mixed together, I've decided to lay them all out & know what each one does. *Yours may be different*

Here's what I observed. If you have the connections down and the buzzer away from you so you're looking at the back of the board There are solder points. The upper left solder point is filled on the active buzzer.  *note* don't count the larger mounting hole on the very edge. In the photo, I've highlighted the filled solder hole on the active buzzer.

[highlighted solder point on active buzzer -- left vs passive buzzer -- right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQtb1.jpg)

I had this same question, which led me here.  The other answers were helpful in and of themselves, but I noticed the difference after testing, and hopefully someday this may help someone else who may be new, as I am now.

I've been at arduino just shy of 2 weeks.